# Inheritance Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, permissions, inheritance

I had full control to a sub-site and removed the inheritance from the parent site by mistake.  Our Sharepoint Administrator does not know how to do this.  She was able to get to the parent and re-add our AD group.  Is there a way she can go to the sub-site and re-add the inheritance to the parent group?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the subsite (the site you want to inherit from the parent), **Site Actions** > **Site Permissions** > select **Inherit Permissions** (in the **Permission Tools** menu).

This will inherit permissions from the parent site once again.